# Google Cloud API not returning any response

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, google-cloud-vision

Background information:
I'm trying to create a PoC for Google Cloud Vision API using their [.NET library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet).

What I have done:
Create a simple console apps with the following code for Vision API.

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleCredentialFile"]);
Grpc.Core.Channel channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());
var client = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);

var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\u065340\Documents\sample.jpg");
var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
foreach (var annotation in response)
{
    if (annotation.Description != null)
    result = annotation.Description;
}
```

Problem:
The line `client.DetectLabels(image)` gets stuck for a long time before ultimately throwing the error `Deadline Exceeded`.
My code sits behind a corporate proxy, but I have validated that it is not blocking internet access because I can call https://vision.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1 from the same apps and get its JSON response just fine.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a long time"? One thing that's entirely possible is that your proxy is fine for HTTP/1.1 but is misbehaving with HTTP/2.0 which gRPC uses. Can you try the same code from home?

Comment: I am also getting same in this line getting system loading : var response = client.DetectLabels(image); . @JonSkeet

Comment: @zahed: Without any more information, it's hard to get any further. There are all kinds of variables here - the platform it's running on, any proxies involved, the version of .NET it's using etc.

Comment: For me its showing error after 20 minths: An exception of type 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' occurred in Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail="Deadline Exceeded") . @JonSkeet

Comment: @zahed: Right. That's a start, but there's all the other information that's important. Is this a console app, a web app, something else? Are you running it from a dev machine, or is it on Azure, AWS, GCP, somewhere else? What's the proxy situation? Are you able to use any other gRPC-based APIs?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'll try to answer your questions. This is a windows form app running on Windows 7 SP1 under .NET 4.5 in a local dev machine. By "a long time", I mean ~ 10 minutes. The full exception is exactly the same as zahed's (RpcException). For the last 2 questions, I don't know how to verify it.. could you please explain what I should do?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Additional info, I have tried that code in my home PC using Visual Studio 2013 without any proxies and I get "This API need Billing Account" as expected in ~ 2 seconds since I haven't setup billing account. However, in my office environment I get that "Deadline Exceeded" after waiting ~ 10 minutes.

Comment: Okay, if you don't have a way of using a GCP account from home, I can see how that makes things trickier. When you say that in your office environment you get the Deadline Exceeded error after 10 minutes, is that with the same credentials as fail with "This API needs a billing account" at home? If so, that really does sound like a proxy issue. (If you were using your corp credentials from the office, can you *try* your non-billing-account credentials instead, just for testing purposes?)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes. Both "Deadline Exceeded" and "This API needs a billing account" are using the same JSON file credential, the difference being that one is run behind corporate proxy and the other from home without proxy. What kind of checking should I do with this proxy?

Comment: If I checked proxy information using chrome://net-internals/#http2, the result is HTTP/2: Enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around through github issues related to proxies as suggested by Jon Skeet, I found that Google Cloud Client APIs can be generally divided into 2 categories (Ref: [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/guides/api-layers.html)): REST-based HTTP 1.1 with JSON and gRPC.
For APIs associated as REST-based, there should be no issue with proxies. The problem starts to appear when we are using gRPC-based APIs such as Google Cloud Vision and Google Speech. In gRPC, we need to explicitly provide our proxy server information.

For those using Java Client, it seems we still can't set proxy properly because it will eventually be ignored, and causing the `Deadline Exceeded` error. This issue is already well known and can be found at [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/1061) and further traced into [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/2775).
The Google team has determined that it is indeed a bug, and the status remains Open.

As for C# Client, we can set proxy information using gRPC Environment Variables which is documented in [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md).  The code is `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("http_proxy", <your_proxy_server>);`
After I set the `http_proxy` environment variable pointing to my proxy server, all is well again. I get the expected output "This API needs Billing Account".

Many thanks to Jon Skeet for pointing me in the right direction :D

Comment: Glad I could help - thanks for taking the ball and running with it, so to speak :)